# create a pairs of users ids with python

Tags: python, twitterapi-python, twitter-follow

I have two lists of users, early adopters and followers. I want to create a pair of users like

(early_adopter, follower). For example:

```
#in 
early_adopters = [1, 2, 3]

#out
follower_list = [(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,e),(3,f)]
```

In my code below, I can retrieve the follower list but this doesn't specify who follows whom.

```
follower_list = []
early_adopters = [1, 2, 3]

for usr in ea:
  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr).items():
    if user.id not in ea:
      follower_list.append(user.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```
follower_list = []
early_adopters = [1, 2, 3]

for usr in early_adopters:
  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr).items():
    if user.id not in early_adopters:
      follower_list.append((usr, user.id))
```

This stores a tuple of `(early_adopter, follower)` in the followers_list.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason did not work for me before. Now it is working. Do you think is possible to use as early_adopter list, a column of dataframe. if "a" is a dataframe, early_adopter = a['user_id'].

Comment: When I use the "user_id"  from the dataframe column, my code doesn't append a pair of users for each element of the list just the first one. However, It works if write the user_ids in a list.

Comment: I don't understand where dataframes are coming from, perhaps it's best to open a new question?